# How to trigger an element visibility only for the clicked item in a v-for loop?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

How do I make each button inside of each element to only trigger the hidden menu of the clicked item, instead of all of them?

```
<div v-for="(i, index) in 3">
  <v-btn @click="clicked = !clicked">Menu</v-btn>
  <p v-show="clicked">hidden menu</p>
</div>

...

data () {
  return {
    clicked: false
  }
}
```

**Codepen:** https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wmjKXB?editors=1010

What would be the best way to do it? I've been looking for an answer but couldn't find anything.

Comment: [One possibility](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/KoRdLW?editors=1010).  [And another](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/eMrpay?editors=1010). Basically you need something to track the visibility of each menu independently.

Comment: @Bert thanks for an example. Though, it feels like an overkill. I would imagine Vue would have a simpler way to make something like this work

Comment: Well typically, you would iterate over some set of menu objects, and each menu object would have a `visible` property. Your issue is that you are not doing anything like that, you are just using a range, so you have to create some data structure to hold the visibility of each of your menus.

Comment: @Bert Yeah, that makes sense. Thanks for explaining!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an array of objects and toggle each using the arrays index corresponding to the button.

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
     data () {
       return {
         clicked:[{ show:true}, { show:true}, { show:true}]
       }
     }
})
```

[Here's a simple example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gezPOp?editors=1010)

Comment: Thanks, looks like that's the way to go.